# Set up dot instead of comma in numeric values

Tags: c#, xml, tostring, numeric, culture

I have new XmlDocument object, i.g. xml is created during my program...

I want all numeric values in created xml was with dot symbol instead of comma by default.

Can I do something to declare it once, not to parse every decimal value?

I.e. To set up this dot instead of comma somewhere in the beginning and don't worry about this till the end?

Comment: If you want a decimal dot in XML but want to use a decimal comma when displaying values to users, you will have to specify it on the spot. There is no "use dot only in xml" setting.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
```

Comment: Why not just directly assign NumberDecimalSeperator in CurrentCulture?

Comment: @Brent Visual Studio shows an error which says "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'CultureInfo.NumberFormat'.". So, it is required to create an instance to reach to the related property.

Answer (score 30):

You can use `value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` to convert your numeric values to strings. Or you can globally change the current culture to a culture that uses the dot as the decimal separator:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
```

Comment: `value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` does not currently work: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29dxe1x2(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Jonas, the link you pointed to is about `String.ToString(IFormatProvider)`. The part about how this parameter is "reserved" doesn't apply to other types, only String

Comment: In my Version (.NET 4.5) it is `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")`. Works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, works great except I also need GetCulture**Info**.

Comment: This is a much better solution for the intended purpose than the accepted answer!

Comment: Beware also of the group separator - if you print numbers as "N", you will get , (comma) as group separator, which might be not what you want for XML.

Answer (score 9):

Use [Decimal.ToString(..)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ebe5aks.aspx) with `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` like a paramater applied.

or if you want to do it globaly, use

[CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) to set to always `Invariant` one, by using [Applicaton.CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.currentculture.aspx) property.

Comment: Setting Application.CurrentCulture didnt work for me.