# How to check and see if a number contains a decimal?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a pretty basic calculator application. I'm running into a problem with decimals. I'm pretty new to C#, so I don't really know what to do here. When I click on the decimal button in my calculator, I want it to check the number in a textbox and see if it already has a decimal. If so, then do nothing. If it does not have a decimal already, append the decimal to the number. Basically I want to keep the user from being able to enter more than one decimal into an operand.

How could I go about testing that number to see if it contains a decimal already?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well it sounds like you're actually wanting to test whether a *string* already contains a decimal point - not a *number*.

Assuming you're not trying to internationalize this, you probably just want:

```
if (textBox.Text.Contains("."))
{
    // We've already got a decimal point; skip this input however you want
}
```

(Note that both `...Contains('.')` and `...Contains(".")` will work, but the former uses LINQ unnecessarily, so I've changed to the latter.)

If you *do* want to internationalize it, you'd want to use `Culture.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator`, to detect what you should display on the button, to check whether or not it's already present, and what to add afterwards. This all affects how you eventually parse the number, too.

Comment: How do you know all these internals of a language? Ok, you are the author of C# in depth, but how???

Comment: @AmitJoki: Just a lot of time spent using the language and reading the spec, really...

Comment: @AmitJoki: Yes, but I'm afraid this sort of thing really isn't appropriate for an SO comment thread.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea you could check a string for a character that easily. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @JonSkeet But what does the latter use?

Comment: @Jon Skeet you are awesome sir. your answers always seems to be depth in that topic

Comment: @AmitJoki: It uses the method in `String` itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
decimal number;
if(Decimal.TryParse(numberTextBox.Text, out number))
{
 //append decimal point to the entered text
}
else
{
 //do nothing
}
```

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18449419/419556

Answer (score 0):

change the input to string then check using

```
String s1="20.12"
b = s1.Contains(".");
```

it will return true if it exist