# Issue with string formatting in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a string variable x with value 2.54, During the time of binding this value in to my ui it displays like 2,54. I know this is something related device's current culture. But i dnt know how to fix this issue. I am new to visual studio & and don't much about string formatting . Please anyone help me to fix this issue.

```
double x = 2.54;
displayValue = x.ToString(); // Here display value is the property which i bind in to UI. There is nothing much in my code.
```

Comment: Posting the failing code is the better way to get a precise answer.

Comment: Search for c# dot coma problem on google you will get a lot of answers
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160059/set-up-dot-instead-of-comma-in-numeric-values

Comment: Yes. No matter what the device culture is, I always want to display it in US culture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What *is* your issue? That you want to display a number to the user by disregarding their selected locale?

If so, then you can probably use the invariant culture:

```
displayValue = x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This is a good bet for numbers that need to be consumed by other programs or embedded in generated source code. For dates it's nigh-useless.

To use a specfic locale, you can use e.g.

```
CultureInfo.GetCulture("en-us")
```

Generally you should respect the user's settings, though. When I have an app telling me how far I've run I would expect the number to match my regional settings.

Comment: I tried this but still it is showing "," instead of "."

Comment: Are you binding to `x` instead of `displayValue` maybe?