# NumericUpDown: accept both comma and dot as decimal separator

Tags: c#, decimal, numericupdown

There's a way to force c# NumericUpDown to accept both comma and dot, to separate decimal values?

I've customized a textbox  to do it (practically replacing dots with commas), but I'm surprised that there isn't another way..

[**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160059/set-up-dot-instead-of-comma-in-numeric-values) question explains how to change the separator, but I would like to use both!

Comment: Why do you want to be able to use both? If it is for several application deployment / users, you should use their local culture, because allowing comma AND dot as a decimal separator can be very confusing for some users.
And the NumericUpDown does not allow this behaviour. You can force comma/dot conversion on valueChanged or keydown maybe?

Comment: The problem is that using the other separator doesn't give an error: it simply ignores it making serious mistakes, and I want to avoid it. I'm working on a commercial software, and silently convert 10.22 to 1022 can be a big problem!!

Comment: @Nicolas R: Values accessible in valueChanged and keydown events are already converted (the wrong separator has been removed), and I can't go back to the inserted value...

Comment: Use KeyPress instead (look at my answer)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

NumericUpDown control uses the culture of the operating system to use comma or dots as a decimal separator.

If you want to be able to handle both separators and consider them as a decimal separator (ie: not a thousand separator), you can use Validation or manual event treatment, for example:

```
private void numericUpDown1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar.Equals('.') || e.KeyChar.Equals(','))
        {
            e.KeyChar = ((System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator.ToCharArray()[0];
        }
    }
```

In this example you will replace every dot and comma by the NumericDecimalSeparator of the current culture

Comment: very smart solution!

Answer (score 4):

The [solution provided by Nicolas R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24311556/2279200) wouldn't work if you paste values into the NumericUpDown (via ClipBoard and Ctrl+V).

I suggest the following solution:
The NumericUpDown Control has, like other Controls, a Text property. But, it is hidden from the designer and Intellisense.
Using the Text property, you can write the ValueChanged event handler like this:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    numericUpDown1.Text = numericUpDown1.Text.Replace(',', '.');
}
```

See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cs40s7ds.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For the standard NumericUpDown control, the decimal symbol is determined by the regional settings of the operating system.