# XCeed Extended Toolkit MaskedTextBox Format behavior

Tags: formatting, format, xceed

I'm using Xceed Extended Toolkit Masked TextBox in WPF 4.5 with C#.

I have a simple MaskedTextBox:

```
<xctk:MaskedTextBox Text="{Binding CNPJ}" Mask="00.000.000/0000-00"/>
```

The problem is, when application is running the dots in the mask are replaced by commas:

[image]

How can I make the Mask use dots instead of commas?

Comment: You cant try set the culture info. Check bang's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160059/set-up-dot-instead-of-comma-in-numeric-values

Answer (score 4):

input \ before ".", example:
Mask="00\.000\.000/0000-00"