# C# How to change DataSet.GetXml() decimal separator to ","

Tags: c#, xml, dataset, decimal, separator

My default decimal separator is "," when calling method myDataSet.GetXml() all decimal values from myDataSet are saving to XML with dot "." separator. The problem is, when I want to parse this XML back to myDataSet, and VS throws me Exception that decimal field accepts only decimal values, because of this separator.

**Example how i get XML:**

```
var xml = myDataSet.GetXml(); //Gives me XML with dots in decimals
```

**Example how i try parse to DataTable:**

```
var recordsDeleted = new DataTable(); //In my code I clone table from existing
recordsDeleted.Columns.Add("decimalFirst", typeof(decimal));
recordsDeleted.Columns.Add("decimalSecond", typeof(decimal));
recordsDeleted.Columns.Add("text", typeof(string));

var paramsToDataTable = new List<string> {"12.34","22.22","Foo"}; //This comes from XML
recordsDeleted.Rows.Add(paramsToDataTable.ToArray());
```

Please help me, how to change separator when saving to XML, or other solution to solve problem when parsing. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9160150/5351370

Comment: Sure, but when i have to call this code? Before every call GetXml() method or somewhere in startUp class?

Comment: Depends on where you do your work. If it's on the main thread you call it once in the beginning. If you spawn new threads for every time you call `GetXml()` you call it before calling `GetXml()` in your new thread.

Comment: "The problem is, when I want to parse this XML back to myDataSet" - how are you doing that? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I've tried to change seperator to "," by code You've sent to me one line before GetXml(), and method saved XML with dots again. I also tried to change seperator to "." just before parsing to myDataSet, and this also not worked.

Comment: @JonSkeet      This is how I parse XML to myDataSet, exactly to DataTable http://static.pokazywarka.pl/a/4/p/524c61643906d37e48ae1eea2552ca5b_big.jpg?1499766672

Comment: No, we don't want a link to a screenshot - please put a [mcve] *in the question*.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've edited question

Comment: But you still haven't provided a [mcve]. We can't copy, paste, compile and run. (It's not clear why you're not calling `DataSet.ReadXml` or `DataTable.ReadXml` to reverse the operation...)

Comment: Why the insistence on an MCVE?  It's clear what's going on.  DataSet.GetXml() will of course export decimal values with a period separator.  Attempting to add a string value to a decimal column will result in a conversion using the Locale of the DataTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataSet.GetXml()` exports decimal columns with a period separator as you've noted.  You can't change this: XML schema numeric data types always use a period separator.

However, this code:

```
recordsDeleted.Rows.Add(paramsToDataTable.ToArray());
```

will attempt to convert each value in `paramsToDataTable.ToArray()` to the appropriate data type using the culture of the `DataTable`.

This culture defaults to `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, but you can override it as follows:

```
var recordsDeleted = new DataTable();
recordsDeleted.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

You should note that it would be more usual to read XML into a `DataTable` using `DataTable.ReadXml()`.  If you do this, you won't need to be concerned about cultures / locales.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the CulutreInfo With the numberseperator as , at the start of the application